# Passing other language data into text file through excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, text

**Problem A**

I have other language data which I am trying to print it in debug window however it excludes the special character

For eg :

1. "Aragac̣otn" is taking as "Aragac?otn".
2. "Ge**ġ**ark'unik'" as "Ge**g**ark'unik'"

In short what can be the appropriate data type for this? I tried with string/variant but no success.

**Problem B**

My ultimate goal is to pass it into txt file. when I am trying to pass the value "Aragac?otn" it throws error. (Invalid Procedure call or argument)

I am using FileSystemObject to this.

Here is image of Problem A

[image]

Comment: The VBE's Immediate window cannot display those characters. That does not mean that you have collected them incorrectly. The same holds true for a prompt thrown into a MsgBox. If you plan on building a TXT out of the results, you will likely have to use UTF-8 encoded though. The string type vars should be sufficient. Try putting them back into the worksheet in a different location.

Comment: @Jeeped actually I would like to build .sql file out of it. Not exactly txt. I am not sure how to make UTF-8. Can you please help me out

Comment: You can build an XLSX for import or use write to SQL directly.

Comment: @Jeeped I am writing it to SQL using filesystemobject. It throws error as stated in Problem B

Comment: The phrase *"writing it to SQL"* makes no sense to me. I don't even know if this is MS SQL, mySQL or some other derivative. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba) will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Output to file using UTF-16](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092548/vba-output-to-file-using-utf-16)

Comment: @Jeeped I meant I am writing it to .sql file (extension). Anyways UTF - 8 resolution should work. WIll try and let you know. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code. It will take values from excel and paste it  in txt file.

```
Sub try()
Dim A1 As Variant
Dim A2 As Variant
Dim sFileName As String
Dim fsT As Object

A1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
A2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value


sFileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\vnpasump\Desktop\test1.txt"


Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object

fsT.WriteText A1
fsT.WriteText A2

fsT.SaveToFile sFileName, 2 'S


End Sub
```